# Dropbox folder in Dock is now just showing a 'blank' blue folder

Tags: finder, dock, dropbox

All of a sudden in the dock (next to downloads folder etc) the dropbox folder is just showing as a plain blue regular mac folder.

[image: How dropbox is looking in the dock]

It still looks correct in Finder

[image: How dropbox looks in Finder]

And also in Get Info

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling but it just put a 'plain' folder back into the Dock. Any suggestions?

[image: How dropbox looks in Get Info]

Comment: In Finder does Dropbox show as a location? If so what is its directory?

Comment: Yes its completely normal in Finder. HD > Usrs > my username > dropbox (next to downloads, desktop etc). Nothing else has changed and it all functions fine just the icon has weirdly disappeared

Comment: What is the full path name in Finder?

Comment: the full path is as above Macintosh HD> Users > username > Dropbox: /Users/username/Dropbox

Comment: Is that the Dock link or from Finder link?

Comment: That is the Finder - select in Finder - View: Show Path

Comment: Found solution. Bizarrely it had changed to 'Display as Stack' rather than Display as Folder. and this seems to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it had changed from display as 'Folder' to display as 'Stack' which caused this behaviour.